# Running GWT on Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on a client's request to make a simple widget in GWT. I am just tyring to setup the environment with Eclipse Oxygen and the GWT plugn in Eclipse's Market. When I run wizard project (Debug as -> GWT development mode). I get this :  "put dev on / dev off buttons in bookmark bar and when on module press dev on" any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you use development mode you start two servers
* codeserver at 9876, which is the one you are opening, it suggests to add those bookmarks and you can clean the code compilation cache
* jetty dev server at 8888, which serves the static files in your webapp folder and the servlets

So, open the 8888 server, go to the path and file you have configured your GWT bootstrapper (the html file containing your {app}.nocache.js file). If you are using a modern version of GWT it should start compiling automatically, but if not just use the 'dev on' bookmark.